# Number Formatting in Codeigniter View

Tags: codeigniter, parsing, number-formatting

i want to know how to format the parsing result in view. What i mean something like this

Controller :

```
public function index(){
    $data=array("test1"=>10000);
    $this->load->library('parser');
    $this->parser->parse("viewPage",$data);
}
```

and the view (viewPage.php) is :

```
test 1 : {test1} <br/>
```

how to make it show 10,000.00. Not 10000

Comment: you can use the simple php [number_format()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) as `echo number_format((10000), 2);`

Comment: sorry you need to parse like `echo number_format({test1}, 2)`